# sharepoint 2013 user field value types?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013, spuserfield

i would like to read a user field value from `properties.AfterProperties`(or the list item) in an ItemUpdating event receiver and get a `SPUser` (or at least a `SPFieldUserValue`) object so i tried:

```
var fldValue = properties.AfterProperties[fldName] ?? properties.ListItem[fldName];
result = (SPFieldUserValue)fldValue;
```

an exception informed me that i cannot cast from `string` to `SPFieldUserValue`. debugging confirmed that the field value type is string.

in this case the user field is declared as `Type="User"` in the list schema, other user fields in the same list are declared as `Type="UserMulti"` and for those the field value *is* of type `SPFieldUserValueCollection`...

now i'd like to know if this is the way sharepoint handles user fields in general or if this is just a bug in a badly configured vm?
because handling single and multi user fields differently isn't that bad, i just need to know if i can rely on those types for field values: 
single user field -> string and multi user field -> SPFieldUserValueCollection?